# How to create child form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with javascript/jquery and right now I have button "Add task",whenever i click on that button then "multiple form" creating with "add subtask" button but i want to add one more thing:

Whenever i click on any "Add subtask", then another form should appear in front of "Main form (parent form)"

Here is my current code:

```js
var count = 0;
$('.buttonClass').click(function() {
  count += 1;

  $("<form name='myform''/>").appendTo('body');
  $("<input placeholder='this is a main task'/>").appendTo('body');
  $("<input type='submit' name='' value='Add subtask'/>").appendTo('body');
  $("<br>").appendTo('body');
  $("</form/>").appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttonClass">Add Task</button>
```

Comment: Perhaps jQuery's [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method would be helpful?

Comment: @mykaf can you please explain or update my answer so i can check

Comment: Did you look at the linked documentation? That should explain. You want to create another form in front of ("before") "Main" form. Are you confused by something in the documentation?

Comment: @freedomn-m okay forget the "form", But how can i add "subtask" ( further fields) in front of main button(add task)  ?

Comment: @freedomn-m my task is simple, let me explain , i have a button "add task" so whenever we click on "add task" then "textbox with "subtask" " button showing ( can be multiple) so i want if i click on any "subtask" button then further new "texbox" and "submit" button should display in front of parent category/button

Comment: @freedomn-m can you share link of jsfiddle ?

Comment: @freedomn-m your code in jsfiddele not working properly , i mean whenever i click an "addsubtask" then all forms are not showing ( hide on click) but i want whenever i click on "addsubtask" then new textbox with submit button should display in front of that button(parent)

Comment: As mentioned previously, you'll need *event delegation* for the newly added button.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Please [edit] your question with all your requirements.  As it is right now, it's very confusing with "add another form" but no reference to that form.  Your comment above *seems to* contradict the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, i.e. a second handler for "Add subtask", that inserts the input before the current block:

```js
var count = 0;
$('.addTask').click(function() {
  count += 1;
   $('#taskForms').append($(`
      <li>
        <form>
          <ol class="subtasks"></ol>
          <div>
            <input placeholder='this is a main task'/>
            <button class="addSubtask" type='button'>Add subtask</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </li>
   `))
});

const subtaskHTML =`
      <li>
        <input placeholder='this is a subtask task'/>
        <button class="prependSubtask" type='button'>Add subtask</button>
      </li>
   `

$('#taskForms').on('click', '.addSubtask', function(){
  $(this).closest('form').find('ol').append($(subtaskHTML))
});


$('#taskForms').on('click', '.prependSubtask', function(){
  $(this).parent().before($(subtaskHTML))
});
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="taskForms">
  <button type="button" class="addTask">Add Task</button>
</ol>
```

Comment: @Mortiz Ringler : your code is working but there is only thing is missing , as i mentioned , with "subtask textbox" i want another "add subtask" button which works same , and can you write number in front of main task and subtask ? for example "task 1" and subtask "1.1"  or "1.2" and so on..

Comment: can you change ?

Comment: gee, I forgot what a massacre jQuery is... Check the updated answer